# Registering common Qt meta types in multiple DLLs

Tags: c++, qt, dll

We have a plug-in based GUI that uses Qt, but not Qt plug-ins.  Plug-ins are loaded dynamically based on the needs of the GUI, and it's possible that the same plug-in may be loaded and unloaded multiple times in a single session.  To date, we have had each plug-in register and unregister its meta types as it is loaded and unloaded, as each plug-in had its own unique set of types that it needed to pass through signals/slots.

After a recent refactoring project, we moved some types into a common location so that they can be re-used across two of our plug-ins.  The issue we are now facing is that if both plug-ins are loaded simultaneously, the first one to get unloaded will unregister the meta types in use by both plug-ins.  This causes our signal/slot connections to no longer function in the plug-in that is still loaded.

I think we may be able to solve this problem by doing reference counting on the registration of each metatype, but that sounds like it may be overkill.  Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, metatype registration [doesn't keep an internal reference count](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetatype.cpp.html#877). It is a no-op when the type is registered. You'll have to do the reference counting yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: I was hoping that there was something I was just missing, but I guess not!  Reference counters it is...